# How to convert any HTTParty.get response to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, encoding, utf-8

A service should read XML files from several sources

```
response = HTTParty.get(url)
if response.code == 200
  if response.headers['content-type'] and response.headers['content-type'].to_s.downcase.include?('utf-8')
    @xml = response.body
  else
    @xml = response.body.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
  end
end
```

Actually, this code works only if XML is on `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1`.

How to convert any kind of source to `UTF-8`?

And,is there a way to know the encoding of response when `content-type` and `xml header tag` do not specify encoding?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the encoding of a string by calling `encoding` on it:

```
"some string".encoding
#=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

And you can encode a string by calling `encode` and passing in an encoding:

```
"some string".encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
```

More info here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Encoding.html